# Converting IL to C# with no syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, cil, .net-reflector

I'm looking for a program that will show me the lowest level (ie. no syntactic sugar) C# code given IL code.

I tried using .NET Reflector to view a .exe file that contained a simple console app with a `foreach` loop, hoping to see `GetEnumerator()`, `MoveNext()`, `Current` etc, however it showed it as a `foreach` loop.

Does such a program exist? Or is it possible to select "no syntactic sugar" in .NET Reflector?

Comment: The target for Reflector would be to recover as much syntactic sugar as possible. What would you like to see for a lambda or an async method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current versions of [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) have a sizable set of options for enabling/disabling decompiler transformation features:

```
...
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            foreach (var arg in args) {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }
        }
...
```

[image]
If needed, you could go further than this by stripping out logic in `ICSharpCode.Decompiler.IL.Transforms.*` and `ICSharpCode.Decompiler.CSharp.StatementBuilder`; Perhaps open an issue asking, whether a PR for your changes would be appreciated, as most of these "rawness" settings have been added relatively recently.

---

#### A better example with enumerators

A laconic snippet of code

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
foreach (var num in numbers) Console.WriteLine(num);
```

compiles to

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
list.Add(0);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> numbers = list;
System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Enumerator enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        int num = enumerator.Current;
        System.Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
finally
{
    ((System.IDisposable)enumerator).Dispose();
}
```

(as seen with all transformation settings disabled)

---

#### Further on for-loops:

As far as compilation goes, `for (a; b; c) d` is the same as `a; while (b) { d; c; }` (save for placement of continue-label), so decompilers will take liberty with deciding what kind of loop it might have been based on context similarity between init-statement, condition, and post-statement, so you might even write code by hand

```
var a = 0;
while (a < args.Length) {
    Console.WriteLine(args[a]);
    a++;
}
```

that will be detected as a for-loop (for there is no telling in IL)

```
for (int a = 0; a < args.Length; a++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(args[a]);
}
```

Comment: In your screenshot, it's showing a for loop. But behind the scenes a for loop is not used for a foreach, right? It uses a while loop.

Comment: Added a few more examples illustrating what's happening - actual enumerable objects will use an enumerator + while-in-a-using (the later becomes a try-finally); foreach on raw arrays uses an inline pattern (likely for performance/redundancy reasons)

Answer (score 2):

On [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933398/converting-il-to-c-sharp-with-no-syntactic-sugar#comment102283731_57933545) to YellowAfterlife OP said:

> In your screenshot, it's showing a for loop. But behind the scenes a for loop is not used for a foreach, right? It uses a while loop.

When iterating over an array it does not use an enumerator object. It uses an integer index counter variable instead. *You know, like a for loop.* The IL uses `OpCodes.Br_S` and `OpCodes.Blt_S`, which we could say are "goto". Sure, you could write it as a `while` loop if you insist.

For test, I wrote this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var index = 0;
    while (index < args.Length)
    {
        var arg = args[index];
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        index++;
    }
}
```

This is what ILSpy output:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < args.Length; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[index]);
    }
}
```

In fact, in the IL, the check was moved after the loop, with a jump to it at the start. Please remember that `while` loop (unlike the `do ... while` loop) is supposed to check before. See the IL:

```
// for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
IL_0001: stloc.0
// (no C# code)
IL_0002: br.s IL_0010
// loop start (head: IL_0010)
    // Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
    IL_0004: ldarg.0
    IL_0005: ldloc.0
    IL_0006: ldelem.ref
    IL_0007: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    // for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    IL_000c: ldloc.0
    IL_000d: ldc.i4.1
    IL_000e: add
    IL_000f: stloc.0

    // for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    IL_0010: ldloc.0
    IL_0011: ldarg.0
    IL_0012: ldlen
    IL_0013: conv.i4
    IL_0014: blt.s IL_0004
// end loop

// (no C# code)
IL_0016: ret
```

Notice `ldlen` which gets the length of an array.

You can verify [this code on ShatpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeBVOVVy6AbEQCwECyAhmAHYAU9ABgDaAXQIcATgHMAzgEoatcotq0AbpII8YAUwAeBALwEBAbhWqCAdwAWkHQV7b9BADzjpMgHQAZHdylgGwVsSyULMKoNCQ8pI1iZIWc9EXNQyNV6AE5eSSk5NIzVZPh4QsiAXwsq7AqgA==).

The compiler is optimizing access to the array. So, we could argue that the compiler turned my `while` loop in a `for` loop.